# Passing null values while using between in a query

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing a stored procedure in T-SQL to select records from the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PHM_News_Entry]
(
    [NewsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NewsTitle] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [NewsDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [NewsDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NewsDateEntry] [datetime] NULL,
    [NewAuthor] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [NewModificationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [NewModifiedBy] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NewsAttatchmentPath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NewsImagePath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
```

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Select_News 
    @NewsTitle VARCHAR(200), 
    @FromDate DATE,
    @ToDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM PHM_News_Entry 
    WHERE (NewsTitle LIKE '%'+@NewsTitle+'%' OR @NewsTitle IS NULL) 
      AND NewsDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate OR NewsDate IS NULL
END
```

The parameters viz., @NewsTitle, @FromDate and @ToDate can either have values or be NULL. If all 3 parameters or NULL, there should be no record selected but if one of them has non-null value, it should select one or more matching records.

If I pass NULL to all 3 parameters, it works as expected i.e., doesn't select any records but it's not working the other way i.e., if one of them one or two of them have non-null values.

Please help me write the correct query for this case.

Thanks and regards,

Shyam Singh

Comment: What behavior do you want if, for example, `@FromDate` be `NULL`, but the other two be non `NULL` ?

Comment: It should select all records up to the ToDate matching the NewsTitle.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (NewsTitle LIKE '%'+@NewsTitle+'%' OR @NewsTitle IS NULL) AND
      (NewsDate BETWEEN COALESCE(@FromDate, CAST('1753-01-01' AS DATE)) AND
                       COALESCE(@ToDate, CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATE)) OR NewsDate IS NULL)
```

**Explanation:**

```
COALESCE(@FromDate, CAST('1753-01-01' AS DATE))
```

This will use the value of `@FromDate` if it be not `NULL`, or it will use the smallest possible date in SQL Server if it is `NULL`.  So when `@FromDate` is `NULL`, then this expression would allow all dates which are earlier than the `@ToDate`.  Similar logic applies for the other `COALESCE` expression.

Comment: I tried executing the procedure after altering it with the WHERE clause from you like this and it selects all records which is unexpected:

`DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[Select_News]
  @NewsTitle = NULL,
  @FromDate = NULL,
  @ToDate = '6/29/2016'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value`

For this execution it should only select records up to 2016-06-29 and not beyond that.

Comment: The query should not be returning records beyond the `@ToDate`.  I added parentheses in the `WHERE` clause, maybe the logic being executed is not what you think.

Comment: Executing the following returns no records now:

`DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[Select_News]
  @NewsTitle = NULL,
  @FromDate = NULL,
  @ToDate = '6/29/2016'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `select` query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   phm_news_entry 
WHERE  ( newstitle LIKE '%' + @NewsTitle + '%' 
          OR @NewsTitle IS NULL ) 
       AND ( newsdate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
              OR @FromDate IS NULL 
              OR @ToDate IS NULL ) 
       AND ( @NewsTitle IS NOT NULL 
              OR @FromDate IS NOT NULL 
              OR @ToDate IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: @ShyamSingh - Can you add Sample data and expected result

Comment: Here's the sql script to create the table with data:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/73a4c53abb44930b2582fa4ba63ddd3e

For expected result, if I execute the procedure with `@FromDate` as `NULL`, `@NewsTitle` as `NULL` and `@ToDate` as `'6/29/2016'`, it should show only one record.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you,

```
SELECT *,
FROM PHM_News_Entry
WHERE (NewsTitle LIKE '%'+@NewsTitle+'%'
       OR @NewsTitle IS NULL)
  AND (NewsDate BETWEEN COALESCE(@FromDate, CAST(NewsDate AS DATE)) AND COALESCE(@ToDate, CAST(NewsDate AS DATE)))
  OR (@NewsTitle IS NULL
      AND @FromDate IS NULL
      AND @ToDate IS NULL) END
```

Answer (score -1):

if one of params is null - whole operator is null - `if SomeThing between @d1 and NULL = null` and `nul or @d = null`
use `isnull` function

```
FROM PHM_News_Entry 
WHERE  NewsDate BETWEEN isnull(@FromDate, '01-01-1753') AND isnull(@ToDate, '01-01-1753') OR NewsDate IS NULL
```